# How to full back lxc container?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I use following command to backup lxc :

```
lxc publish CONTAINER_NAME/SNAPSHOT_NAME --alias my-export
lxc image export my-export .
```

This will create a new LXD image from your container and export it as a tarball in your current directory. You can then ship that tarball to your target host and do:

```
lxc image import TARBALL --alias my-export
lxc init my-export NEW-CONTAINER
```

After import the container,I find the environment variables doesn't backup.
I use command to check the environment variables.

```
env
```

How should I totally backup lxc container?

Thank you very much.